# Hide navigation bar

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 views. (say 1st,2nd,3rd). I have pushed the 2nd view (which has a load view method) on the 1st. In the 2nd view I have created the 3rd using `initWithFrame` (which is inherited from UIWebView). In 2nd view I wrote self.view=3rd view.

Now I want to hide the 2nd view's navigation bar in the 3rd view (i.e., when the user touch to 3rd view screen i.e. UIWebView). I got the touch recognition using gesture, but I can't hide the navigation bar.

3rd view don't support `self.navigationController`. And if I create 2nd view's object in 3rd, it does not hide the navigation bar. Can anybody help me?

Comment: "3 views" should be "3 view controllers" right?

Answer (score 34):

Ok. So you need to set the navigation bar to be hidden right after you create the navigation controller for that tab. You cannot adjust this after you push the view controller (as far as I know).

If you want the first view to not have a navigation bar at the top, then use this in your appDelegate where you initially declare your navigation controllers:

```
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:theViewController];
[localNavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

If you want the views after that to be hidden, then you need a viewController for the subsequent views, and you will have to add

```
[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

right before you call this:

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:theThirdViewController animated:YES];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 18):

Implement this:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

before assign the 3rd view. that is self.view = 3rd view

Comment: Thank u Sisu... But your ans doesn't work.. Using above line, the navigation bar gets hidden, but my problem is not that.. When user clicks on webView(on 3rd view) i want to display and hide the navigation bar of 2nd view... If I use the line u have mentioned above, Bar gets hide, but i can not able to display it again, on user's finger touch on webView.

Comment: `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];`

Use this in 3rd view.

Comment: But there isn't navigationController for 3rd view.. I can not write [self.navigationController .........] in 3rd view.

Comment: Then write this `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];` code in 2nd view delegate _viewDidDisappear:_ or _viewWillDisappear_ method

Answer (score 1):

Note that the code must be added in the viewWillAppear method

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
      self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

     [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: You should definitely not access `self.navigationController` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: @AnhPham I apologize my mistake. I just wanted to help.I will take care of further.